# Spliting a string by capital letters except for certain keywords

Tags: c#, .net, string, list

The following function splits a string at any uppercase character found within the string.

```
public static string ToSentence(this string input)
{
   var list = new List<char>();
    for (var i = 0; i < input.ToCharArray().Length; i++)
    {
        var c = input.ToCharArray()[i];
        foreach (char c1 in i > 0 && char.IsUpper(c) ? new[] {' ', c} : new[] {c})
            list.Add(c1);
    }
    return new string(list.ToArray());
}
```

In my code, this function is being used in conjunction with another function that retrieves the name of the current method in code. I'm finding this function breaks when a method name contains multiple capital letters sequentially.

For example, if I have a method called `GetDatabaseIDE()` it would return as `"Get Database I D E"`

How can I change my `ToSentence` function so that it accepts a list of keywords that won't be split (For example, `I D E` becomes `IDE`)?

Comment: Take out the `ToCharArray()` calls, you're creating a lot of garbage for no reason, since `string` itself allows subscripting.  The inner foreach loop is also terribly overcomplicated for what you are doing.  Just `if (something) { list.Add(' '); } /* always */ list.Add(c);` would be so much faster and also easier to understand.

Comment: BTW, you've described the problem as "breaks when an input contains multiple capital letters sequentially" -- this is a much easier rule to implement than your list of keywords.  Although you might want to split "IHaveBacon" even though there are sequential capitals.

Comment: Assumed that `IDE` is an acronym for something, the faster way likely accomplished using regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495457/split-pascalcase-string-except-for-acronyms.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto: Great find, one of the answers there appears to do exactly the right thing, including on "IHaveBacon".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try Regex ?  Demo @ https://dotnetfiddle.net/FsPZ9O
1. `([A-Z]+)` - match all leading uppercase char.
2. `([^A-Z])*` - followed with zero-or-more of any that isn't an uppercase char.

```
Regex.Matches("GetDatabaseIDE", @"([A-Z]+)([^A-Z])*").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value);
```

Comment: Just found there is already an answer as this mine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495457/split-pascalcase-string-except-for-acronyms

Answer (score 0):

[`TakeWhile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548775(v=vs.110).aspx) method can be useful here, once you find an upper case character, you can take the following upper case characters:

```
for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    var c = input[i];
    if(char.IsUpper(c))
    {
        var charsToAdd = input.Skip(i).TakeWhile(char.IsUpper).ToArray();
        if(charsToAdd.Length > 1)
        {
            i += charsToAdd.Length - 1;
        }

        if(i > 0) list.Add(' ');

        list.Add(charsToAdd);
    }
    else 
    {
        list.Add(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add keywords you want to skip:

```
public static string ToSentence(string input)
{
   var list = new List<char>();
    for (var i = 0; i < input.ToCharArray().Length; i++)
    {
            if(input.IndexOf("IDE",i,input.Length-i)==i){
                list.AddRange(" IDE");
                i+=2; 
            }
            else{
                var c = input.ToCharArray()[i];
                foreach (char c1 in i > 0 && char.IsUpper(c) ? new[] {' ', c} : new[] {c})
                list.Add(c1);
            }
     }
    return new string(list.ToArray());
}
```

watch it  [here](http://rextester.com/DFCFX54398)

Comment: `input.IndexOf(keyword) == i` is not a correct test for whether the keyword appears at position `i`, because `IndexOf` only finds the first occurrence.  Not to mention that searching the entire input for every keyword for every character is rather inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for your example, you will have to tweak it if your method names have numbers in them

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public static string GetNiceName(string testString)
{
    var pattern = "([A-Z][a-z]+)|([A-Z]+)";
    var result = new List<string>();
    foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(testString, pattern))
    {
        result.Add(m.Groups[0].Value);
    }
    return string.Join(" ", result);
}
```